# Puppeteer.js - Remove Chrome background messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, puppeteer, chromium

I'm using the following Puppeeter.js ([puppeteer-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra) is extended package of Puppeeter.js) code in order to create my browser:

```
const puppeteerExtra = require('puppeteer-extra');
const browser = await puppeteerExtra.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--start-maximized'
    ]
});
```

But I keep getting messages like 'Chrome isn't your default browser' Or 'Save credentials' dialog after login. 
How can I permanently remove these messages? Images attached to see what I'm talking about.
Thanks everyone.
**Image 1:**
[image]
**Image 2:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I use `ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']` in order to remove the Chrome message on top "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software".
**Image 3:**
[image]
I want to keep disabling this message (image 3), and also remove theses messages (images 1-2).

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']` is causing both of the issues. By default, Puppeteer launches Chrome using the `--enable-automation` flag which tells Chrome to not prompt to Save password and not show the prompt for default browser check (among other things). More details [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/pull/23#discussion_r138474614)

By specifying this flag in `ignoreDefaultArgs`, you are telling Chrome that it is not being run in automation and so it shows up these prompts. So removing this should solve the problem.

**Update based on update in Question**

Not sure if this suits your usecase, but another possible option is to make Chrome remember your choice by using the `--user-data-dir` flag which would make Chrome store the preference (and other stuff) to a persistent location.

So basically:

1. Add `'--user-data-dir=c:/temp2/'` to the `args` in `puppeteerExtra.launch` call. You might want to change the location there.
2. Launch your script once, which would open up Chrome and it would create the directory mentioned in `--user-data-dir` to save the data. Here, manually close the banner for default browser check. And then manually open the browser settings and disable "Offer to save passwords" option. These preferences would get saved.
3. Close the browser/script.

Subsequently, whenever the script launches Chrome, it uses the preferences you saved and won't present these 2 prompts to user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yaniv, I updated my question accordingly.